# php exec won't execute what is executable in console regarding audio and video

Tags: php, ffmpeg, exec, owner

I have php to run a shell command to start an audio/video stream via ffmpeg. I tried the syntax in the console (as the same user as php [www-data] and from the same location as the php-script:

`pi@raspberrypi:/var/www/html/ $ sudo -H -u www-data ffmpeg {parameters}`

This works nicely. Both audio and video is visible on youtube. When I execute from php with exactly the same parameters

```
$pid = exec("ffmpeg {parameters} 2> out.txt");
```

the response is

`cannot open audio device hw:1,0 (No such file or directory)`

My first guess was that this had something to do with users and groups, but I can't tell what. I even put www-data in the sudo group. Still not working.

If I do

```
exec("whoami 2> user.txt");
```

the file user.txt is created (with owner www-data) but remains empty. Can anyone help me out?

**UPDATE**
When I reboot the pi it works only one time. I think that somehow after closing the stream

```
exec("kill -9 ".$pid);
```

the audio is still busy. The error message is changed in

```
cannot open audio device hw:1,0 (Device or resource busy)
```

The video (via uv4l: localhost:port/stream/video.mjpeg) is available.

Comment: I assume your user executing the php script has to be part of the `audio` group to use alsa.

Comment: Yes, the www-data user is a member of sudo, video and audio.

Comment: Show output of `arecord -l` with the troublesome user.